# Does Facebook Need both og:image and og:image:secure_url for HTTPS only site?

Tags: images, facebook, open-graph-protocol

Now that I updated many of my sites to be HTTPS only, redirecting HTTP requests as needed, I did notice that sharing on Facebook produced a blank image. Refreshing the Share Attachment does not change anything, so I looked into t he FB documentation. It says to specify the `og:image:secure_url` tag if your site requires an HTTPS connection, so I *replaced* the simple `og:image` tag with the secure one and the Facebook OpenGraph Debugger says that `og:image` is missing but the site no longer has any insecure images.

**Must I really set both? And can they both point to exactly the same HTTPS URL?**

Comment: Presumably you mean `og:image:secure_url`?

Comment: @DocRoot - Good catch. Fixed and make sure that was what I actually had on the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it, if your site is 100% SSL (and everything redirects to HTTPS, so there is essentially no plain HTTP) then you only need the `og:image` tag in which you specify the `https://...` URL. Although, must admit, this is not particularly clear from the [OGP documentation](http://ogp.me/) (or [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#images)) - which seems to imply (by example) that the `og:image` URL is HTTP only - this does not appear to be the case.

The `og:image:secure_url` tag is used to specify an *alternative* HTTPS URL ("alternative" being the word used in the [OGP documentation](http://ogp.me/)). This only appears to be required when the site supports both HTTP and HTTPS - when HTTPS is indeed an "alternative".

However, there is no harm in specifying both `og:image` and `og:image:secure_url` and pointing them both at the same `https://...` URL. WordPress appears to do this by default. However, as mentioned, if your site is *only* HTTPS then there does not appear to be a need to specify `og:image:secure_url` as well. Both methods validate OK in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). Both methods "work" in my testing. StackExchange (which is now 100% HTTPS) uses only the `og:image` tag (specifying an `https://` URL)  - which validates and "works" OK.

> Refreshing the Share Attachment does not change anything

Not really sure what you are referring to with regards to "Share Attachment"? But problems like this are often the result of (Facebook) caching. Within the Facebook Debugger, check the "Time Scraped" and hit the "Scrape Again" button if required.

However, there have been numerous queries raised in the past regarding the failure to display the image when URLs are shared. Some "fixes" include:

- Specify a different image URL.
- Specifying `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` tags.
- Having to wait 10 minutes for the FB cache. (!?)
- Image never appearing when the URL is *first* shared. (Because of the FB cache.)

These all appear to relate to the FB cache, so refreshing the request via [FB debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) may be the required fix.

Reference: (however, whilst this question is a few years old, I think some answers may still be relevant)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https

Comment: Going to try some of this today but even the docs you linked to say *og:image:secure_url - An alternate url to use if the webpage requires HTTPS.*. Note the word *requires* which I think is the case for an HTTPS site, or am I misinterpreting something? And, yes, the first share used to not work but doing refresh attachment always fixed it back when the site served both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: @Itai To be honest, the more I think about this the less it seems to make sense. If the `og:image` tag supports both HTTP and HTTPS URLs (as it appears to) then there doesn't seem to be a need for a `og:image:secure_url` tag? The `og:image` tag appears to be mandatory (one of "the four reqd properties for every page" - according to the OGP). "if the webpage requires HTTPS" then only specify HTTPS URLs in the `og:image` tag? Incidentally, YouTube, WordPress.com and Amazon all just use the `og:image` tag with HTTPS. No sign of `og:image:secure_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed content does not apply within those tags therefore the SSL will still work correctly regardless if they are HTTPS or HTTP, however the whole point of SSL is for security and privacy for your users... so, why not gone the whole distance?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your last sentence/question. What do  you mean? This (and most others of my sites) are now completely secure, even most ads are delivered over HTTPS.

Comment: If your site is SSL... why OG non-ssl.

Comment: That's the question. I removed the non-ssl version but FB debugger says it's missing... so maybe the tool is not up to date which is why I am asking.